# How does the first call to previous returns the same element as the last call to next?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

I'm reading [Java Tutorial Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) on List interface and have encountered the following statement:

> Calls to next and previous can be intermixed, but you have to be a bit
>   careful. The first call to previous returns the same element as the
>   last call to next.

I'm struggling to get my head around the phrase: The first call to previous returns the same element as the last call to next. Could someone explain it in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first call to previous returns the same element as the last call to next. Could someone explain it in a bit more detail?

If you say `.next()` and then `.previous()`, you get the same instance because of the internal position of the `Iterator`. Otherwise, consecutive calls to `.next()` would return the *same* **instance**.

```
a b c
  ^
```

`.next()` gives `b`, but moves the pointer to `c`

```
a b c
    ^
```

so `.previous()` then yields `b`.

Comment: so what the tutorial meant is that if I call next() and then call previous(), the same element would be returned, is that correct? The wording of the tutorial is a bit too simple for my liking sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple if you change your mental model. The "cursor" for `next` and `previous` rests *between* elements. When you call `next` or `previous` it moves one element and returns the element it passed over.

It starts out *before* the first element.  The call to `next` returns the element it passes over (the first one) and the cursor stops between the first and second element (elements 0 and 1).

Calling `next` at this point returns the second element and leaves the cursor between the second and third element. If instead you called `previous`, the cursor would back up over the first element and return it, coming to rest before the first element again.

Comment: Elliott Frisch mentioned below that the pointer points to element themselves, however, you have mentioned that cursor points between elements. Are pointer and cursor the same or they are referring to two different concept?

Comment: I am providing a mental model that you can use to predict the behavior.  An `Iterator`'s definition specifies nothing about how it works internally, how it maintains a "pointer" to an element.  My description is an abstraction that captures the behavior of the interface accurately without reference to what is going on "under the covers".  The important point is that an `Iterator` behaves as if the cursor stops between elements. If you think about it that way, the behavior of `next` and `previous` makes sense. This is a useful lesson in the difference between an interface and an implementation.

Comment: ok, so the cursor you have mentioned is part of an mental model used to understand the concept. The pointer is part of how Java implement iterator internally? I hope I got this right

Comment: 100% correct. With an interface you care only about the behavior, not its implementation, since different collections will have different implementations for their iterators.

Answer (score 1):

`list.previous` returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards.Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.

```
ListIterator<Object> iterator = (ListIterator<Object>) myList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Object o = iterator.next();
            Object secondObject = iterator.previous();
            o == secondObject; // ALways
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example will clear your doubt

```
List<Integer> colls = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});

ListIterator<Integer> iterator = colls.listIterator();
iterator.next();
System.out.println("Last Call to next " + iterator.next());
System.out.println("First Call to previous  " + iterator.previous());
```